Accurately Converting Between Binary Floating Point and Decimal Character String.
This must have been studied before, and has been one of the confusion I've been having.
Suppose we want to convert a astronomically big floating point number (so big that it's floating point representation has no fraction part) to a character sequence. A naive way to do this, is divide it by the largest integral power of ten less than it, get the first digit, mod the number with that power of then, then repeat with the next power of ten until we get all the digits.
This method suffers from accuracy problems, stemming mostly from double rounding of exponentiating ten, as well as the division (and modulo) operation.
The method I thought of to get around this, is to put it in an integer, leave at least 5 bits for rounding down. This 5 bits will be used this way:

the least significant 2 bits are used for rounding and tie breaking.

the least significant 4 bits are used to account for division with 10 (since 10 needs 4 bits in binary representation), with the aforementioned 2 least significant bits representing carries and/or borrows from the preceeding division step.

when the scaling of the floating point number is complete, the 5 bits are rounded away.

the resulting character string is padded with "0"s on the right with the number of tens divided.


I didn't manage to come up with detailed rationale/analysis for these steps, and I believe there must be something missing that'll prevent it from working.
I checked FreeBSD source code, and encountered code by David M. Gay, who in 1998 wrote the code while working for Lucent Technologies (according to the license and credits in the source code file), which appears to be using big integers (which is roughly an array of integers that emulates "infinite" precision). Update: It's source code for strtod, which converts a string to number, in this Q I'd like to focus on number to string conversion.
Q What efficient and accurate methods do we use to convert between binary floating point numbers and decimal character strings? What're their numerical analysis properties?

David M. Gay seem to be an expert on this. His code could be worth reading.

You might find reading about Dragonbox useful.  It is a float-to-string (e.g., dtoa-like) algorithm based on work by R. Giulietti.  A reference implementation is available on github 1.  That repository also contains references and links to the algorithms on which it is based.
Dragonbox claims that

the algorithm has been proven correct
guarantees round-trip correctness
the output is of the shortest possible length
the output is correctly rounded

It appears that Dragonbox is used in the fmt open-source formatting library.  See 2.

This is a link-only answer. Yes it had been studied. David M. Gay is indeed an expert on this, and he has a paper on this:

Correctly Rounded Binary-Decimal and Decimal-Binary Conversions David M. Gay, 1990-11-30, URL: https://ampl.com/_archive/first-website/REFS/rounding.pdf

Peaking at concluding remarks, it's said:

In hard cases, we must resort to high-precision integer arithmetic.

this suggests that even the naive and the moderately thoughtful methods in the Q are not sufficient for accurate conversion.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173056/why-does-dtoa-c-contain-so-much-code
